# Can't get postgresql 12 to start as service

Tags: postgresql

Found this error:
/var/run/postgresql/12-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No such file or
directory

Manually creating I can start Postgresql, but has to be recreated every reboot.

This is after a recent upgrade to postgresql 12.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should possibly include a bit more information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem and it turned out that /etc/postgresql/main/12/start.conf was set to "manual".  Changing it to "auto" and rebooting allowed it to start automatically with no intervention.  More details are in this thread: https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2469959